# GraphQL: using input type in Output

Tags: node.js, graphql

I am using graqhql in my React-Node project. I have defined all my graphql types in `.graphql` files. I have a products.graphql where I want to define product types, something like this:

```
input ProductInput {
    label: String
    title: String!
    description: String!
    imageUrl: String!
    productCategory: Electronics | Food | Toy  // this line doesn't work
}

type Product {
    id: ID!
    product: ProductInput!  // throws error
}

type Electronics {
    itemType: String!
    warranty: Int!
}

type Food {
    expiry: String!
    weight: Int!
}

type Toy {
    age: Int!
}
```

I am facing two issues:

1. `ProductInput` takes a `productCategory` type which can be either of these types: `Electronics`, `Food` or `Toy`. Defining union type like `productCategory: Electronics | Food | Toy` throws error. I can solve this by defining the three product categories separately in `ProductInput` by adding a field for each of them, and then picking the first defined field as input in my resolver, but it won't be very elegant.
2. And I still have one more issue: reusing input type `ProductInput` in `Product`. Doing so gives error: `The type of Product.productCategory must be Output Type but got: ProductInput!`.

Is there a way to solve these two issues?

Answer (score 0):

An *input* type can only have scalar fields. You're trying to define `ProductInput` using a complex field.

Furthermore a type cannot be defined using `input` types.

Comment: This will lead to lot of code duplication. Plus it's not clear to me where you used the union `Product` above?

Comment: Actually very little or no code duplication. The core fields can all be resolved by `CoreProduct` - only the extra fields need to be resolved separately. You can use the `Product` type for either query input or output.

Comment: One other limitation with your code is that `Electronics`, `Food`, etc must be `input` and not `type`, as these are part of mutations.